If I escalate a FERPA amendment request, what happens if key evidence(waivers), was lost/destroyed during transition to digital + retention policies?
I discovered information that poses a risk to my privacy due to what I believe was an improper disclosure. I requested to review my education record and obtain documents to support my claim, but the school stated that the records were either destroyed per the retention policy or 'got lost in transition' during digitalization. If the school denies my request and informs me of my right to a hearing, how will the lack of available evidence impact the outcome of my case if I choose to contest the decision?

You testify, they testify
In the absence of the records, you will each give your recollection of what they contained (if relevant). The judge will weigh the testimony and reach a decision.
A court can, but is not required to, presume that records that have been lost or destroyed by one party to the case contained information prejudicial to that party’s case.

On a practical basis, I expect the OP is in a good position. Who in the school administration would remember what was in the lost records? Unless the details under discussion were particularly memorable (e.g. some severe disciplinary issue, as opposed to class grades).
